# How does the Team Player hat get triggered?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

The criteria for the Team Player hat states:

> visit the Stack Overflow for Teams landing page at stackoverflow.com/teams

I've visited the page 30 min ago, scrolled up and down and still haven't gotten the hat.

Is there a bug relating to the hat, if not, how does it get triggered?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Team Player is one of two hats being awarded from our Events database, part of our internal analytics system.  I'm not sure how everything works, but there's queues and batches involved so there can be a substantial delay between when you visit the page and when you get the hat.

(As a dev, it can also be frustrating to roll out something new and just stare at that empty event screen waiting for numbers to come in.)

Comment: I visited the [Teams Landing Webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) at the start of Winter Bash 2018, and again a while ago. Still no hat. Is it possible that some people are being missed. I'll click the link in this comment right after I submit it.

Comment: Team Player hat delivered, I don't know if it was from a week ago, several hours ago or two hours ago; but I only need one. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I just earned it on Stack Overflow.  I visited the team page about an hour ago.  So either the check is infrequent or there was a problem.  Since it's an easy hat to get, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a flood in the first hour or two that caused some delays.

Comment: The check is definitely infrequent.  I visited it three hours ago and STILL no hat.

Comment: I visited roughly 3 hours ago too  - still waiting.

Comment: Update:  I did finally get the hat a few hours after I left the above comment.

Comment: @JamesDunn - my experience is problems are solved immediately after posting about them on SO  (I'm not talk about answers given, just that I always figure it out after going for help)

Comment: @TimTisdall, good to know.  I'll be sure to comment more often.  ;)