# Got Silencium on a question with no answers for 15 min

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I've received the Silencium hat on [a question with no answers for 15 min](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319843/how-does-the-team-player-hat-get-triggered).

Pretty sure it shouldn't be the case:

> ask a question that gets no answers **within a week of being posted**

Comment: Looks like a bug. This user also got it - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/63106/kidburla

Comment: Yep. The relevant query ensured that the question didn't get any answers within 7 days of being posted... But neglected to ensure that it was 7 days old.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is fixed.

That is, it's fixed in the sense that we're no longer awarding Silencium to brand new questions.  As Shog pointed out, we just needed a `and q.CreationDate < DATEADD(d, -7, @Time)` in there.

<s>It's not fixed in the sense that you still have your hat.  I can't say what will happen there because it's late, I'm new to this business, and I don't know what people will say in the morning. In the mean time, you look dashing.</s>

I've been informed that [according to the rules, you get to keep your hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer).

[image: Monopoly card: Bank error in your favor.]